# .NET 6 - Set SelectListItem to Selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `DropDownList` which I populate like below:

**Controller**

```cs
IEnumerable<Category> categories = _db.Category.ToList();

var selectList = _db.Category.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = i.Name,
    Value = i.Id.ToString()
});

ViewBag.categoriesSelectList = selectList;
```

And use in view like so:

```
<select asp-for="Category" name="categoryID" asp-items="@ViewBag.categoriesSelectList" class="form-control">
        <option>Vælg Kategori:</option>
</select>
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how I can set the already selected value, so the dropdown "starts" on that value. I tried enumerating over the `selectList` and changing the `Selected` attribute of the `SelectListItem`, but it doesn't work since it won't save the changes I make.

Hope my question makes sense :) thanks all.

Comment: 1. Through the ViewModel, which you have assigned the value to the `Category` property,  the drop-down list will be *default* with the option (which the value is matched with the `Category` value) is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1:

Modify your code to include `Selected` property when creating list of `SelectListItem` items:

```cs
var selectList = _db.Category.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = i.Name,
            Value = i.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = /* Some condition that is true when the current item should be selected  */
        });
```

## Option 2:

Define a view model with structure that might be referenced in the `<select>` tag:

```cs
public class SelectViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; } 
}
```

The action method:

```cs
public IActionResult Categories()
{
    var model = new SelectViewModel() ;
    model.Categories = _db.Category.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = i.Name,
            Value = i.Id.ToString()
        });

    model.Category = ... your_code_to_set_default_selection;

    return View(model);
}
```

The view:

```
@model SelectViewModel

<select asp-for="Category" asp-items="@Model.Categories"></select>
```

Can find some mode information in the documentation: [The Select Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-select-tag-helper)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot for including the documentation link! I'm still learning "how" to search for .Net related answers because of all the new terminology :) thanks man